# My website contains lots of sub pages, is it the common practice or is there an alternative for that?

Tags: html, web

I am making a website which will have lots of photographs. When a user clicks on a particular photo, a new page will be loaded with that photo being displayed bigger in size. There is a next button which will take the user to another page where there is another photograph. Therefore, my website will have lots of sub webpages( a little more than the number of photographs I have on the website). So is it usually how these kinds of websites are made,i.e., with lots of webpages or is there any other alternative for it?

Comment: Use `include` for that

Comment: We don't know if is using a server side code. Maybe is not php and include is not an option. But in case the OP don't want or know how to use a server side code, maybe a good option could be javascript.

Comment: I would look into using a jquery plugin maybe to contain all these on one page..I must say i have never heard of having a separate page for every enlarged photo..http://fancybox.net/

Comment: @Richlewis This was normal in early fancybox-missing days.

Comment: @frikinside Hmm, yes you're right. However if he can use PHP it should atleast be a great replacement of having a different page for all his photographs

Comment: @DejaVu I agree, but we don't know the server requirements, maybe there's no php avaliable, we don't know. Of course include would get rid the problem, but maybe is not the properly solution in this case.

Comment: @frikinside I see where you're coming from, but untill OP provides me with more information of whether he can or can't use PHP i will leave my answer here just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not the usual aproach, al least on these days.
When we encounter with a similar situation like your case, we usually try to make it dynamic.
For example, if you need to show a lot of photos with the same markup and format, maybe the best option is to have a template with a variable.
The variable will be the photo url and the template will be everything surrounding it.
The page is the same, but only the photo changes.
There are a lot of advantages of doing this. Mainteneance, simplicity, work-load, cache...

Of course that can be use in another cases, like viewing a new details, when you would have only a ViewNew page, and you pass a parameter with the identifier of the new so you can show the correct request.

There are plenty ways to achieve this, most of them require server side code, to handle and process the request, like:

- [PHP](http://www.php.net/)
- [ASP/ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)
- [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/)
- [ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html)
- [Perl](http://www.perl.org/)
- [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/)
- [Phyton](https://www.python.org/)
- ...

But, some of this operations, could be also achieve by javascrip, a client side script code.
You could work with pure javascript or use a framework to make things easy and compatible. Here's some examples of javascript frameworks:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/)
- [Mootools](http://mootools.net/)
- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)
- [Midori](http://www.midorijs.com/)
- ...

I don't know if you want a particular examples using one of this languages or only know alternatives. If you need examples or need more information I'll be pleased of provide some.
Also, It's common that even if you are using a server side code, use javascript too, because can handle the behaviour on the website and/or make [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) request for asyncronous requests.

---

### EXAMPLES

---

- **JavaScript simple**:
  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/FsXxF/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id="previous" onClick="previousImg();">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" onClick="nextImg();">Next</button>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="imgViewer" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mattahan/umicons/256/Number-1-icon.png" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var imgUrlTemplate = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mattahan/umicons/256/Number-$number$-icon.png';

var imgCounter = 1;
var imgViewerNode = document.getElementById("imgViewer");

function previousImg() {
    if(imgCounter > 1) {
        imgCounter--;
        imgViewerNode.src=imgUrlTemplate.replace("$number$",imgCounter);
    }
}

function nextImg() {
    if(imgCounter < 9) {
        imgCounter++;      imgViewerNode.src=imgUrlTemplate.replace("$number$",imgCounter);
    }
}
```

Comment: A third option worth mentioning is a [static site generator](http://staticsitegenerators.net). The benefits being that it makes few or no requirements on either server or client (apart from good old HTTP and HTML(/CSS)).

Comment: Okay, I am not too good with web programming as of now, so may I know more that the thing you mentioned "Template with variable". How do I achieve this. Can this be done by using css? If not then will javascript be enough?

Comment: For Example, look at this site www.listceleb.com. Here, when you click on a picture then another page opens with a bigger picture and I can see the whole gallery by clicking on next. How do I achieve this without creating another page?

Comment: Also, i would like it if you can provide some examples basically written in javascript.

Comment: You're case can be solved perfectly only with javascript, but when you need to handle databases or a lot of procesing, you will need to move to a server side code. But for simple websites, without storing user information, HTML + CSS + JavaScript would be fine. I'm a little busy right now so i cannot put you more examples like I said, but I make a simple example for your case. I'll update the answer with the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 html page and in that you write the PHP `include 'photographlink'` in the body with a case system of some sort. It will use 1 html page and it will include a different photograph depending on which photograpg is clicked

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: There's no PHP Tag or reference by OP. Maybe there isn't any server side code. Please, don't make assumptions.

Comment: @frikinside But there is also no javascript tag or whatever, it's just a general question by the OP, maybe he just wants to hear some alternatives for having a different page for every photo. I'm just giving him one. It may not be the best method. But that's up to OP.

Comment: @reinierpost if that's his real question, than the answer is 'No' that is not how websites do it.

Comment: You are completly right, that's the reason I don't post an answer with javascript thing, but I came up with the javascript stuff because is always avaliable on an html page (well if the user don't disable in his browser of course).

Comment: @frikinside That's true. But as he's saying he is making a website on his own, i can only assume he can use PHP as well. I might be wrong on this one. But that's not up to me.

Comment: And that would be very "risky" on your side. The first "website" I made a loooooooooong time ago has tables, text and images, that's it. Not every web developer in the world must know PHP. I had some workers partners that they never use PHP, and they are web developers. But this is a discussing for another topic, maybe we should end the "offtopic" and focus on the OP request.

Comment: @frikinside I agree, but is it really off-topic? if the OP gave us more details to work with i can only assume things, i can assume he can use PHP and you can assume he can't use PHP. But you're right we should stop this discussion because as long as the OP doens't say anythnig we can argue forever :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to use javascript, my tip is to use jQuery framework to dynamically load and visualize images. You can find in the web some plugins that can simplify your life.

[demo of one plugin](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/index.php?c=effects)